# Fast way to dynamically update an SQL table

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures

Currently, I am taking imported data from a process and doing a MERGE to a temp table with specific data to use to do some calculations and putting the data into it's proper locations in the tables on our end.  The issue I am having is that one of the columns is a state column in which data is provided to us in a very poor manner.  data is populating the column in several different formats like texas, tx, Mt..

Is there a way within the merge to take out that "." at the end of the abbreviation or dynamically change states that are spelled out to their abbreviation?  If not within the merge after the data gets set in the temp table, is there a way to run something like a quick update statement without having to go write it out 50 times for each state?  I am still relatively new to SQL and the only answer I can think of to fix this in a fast manner is to have a bunch of update statements run in sequence, but writing out 50 update statements seems to be over kill and I imagine there has to be a better way to do this without looping row by row for roughly 40,000~ records or so at a time.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understood correctly,

```
UPDATE YourTable set StateCol = replace(StateCol,'.','')
```

Try this, replacing the dot with an empty string.

Comment: awesome that should take care of part of the issue!  Actually didn't think about that!  Would you have an idea how to dynamically change the state names to their abbreviation?

Comment: @ggiaquin what do you mean by that? give me examples

Comment: So i have the data coming in as Texas, AK, Maine, NJ, tx, mt, alaska as the raw data in the column.  I want to be able to pluck out the full names like texas, maine, alaska, and replace them with their abbreviation without having to do a loop (as I am trying to reduce the time this process takes).

Comment: Mmm, the only way this is possible, is if you have a table containing both all the states names and all the states abbreviation @ggiaquin . do you?

Comment: Yes, I have a look up table.

Comment: Ok, so make an update with join, and use case when your column = abbrevation that update to fullname @ggiaquin

Comment: ok so doing a case statement for the 50 states would be the only way to do it without looping is what i think you are saying right?

Comment: Well, now that i think about it you dont need a case statement.. not to familiar with tsql syntax but something like: update table set t1.statecol =  lkp.fullname from table t1 innerjoin lookup lkp on (t1.statecol = lkp.abbrevation ) @ggiaquin tell me if it works and in addition i'll appreciate a V

Comment: This appears to be working so far Thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the merge statement. This is useful when you have to update large amounts of data:

```
MERGE Yourtable AS target
USING ( select stateName,StateAbr from TableAbrv) AS source 
ON (target.stateName= source.stateName)
WHEN MATCHED then update 
set  target.stateName = source.StateAbr
```